# Storing unicode values & using formatting

Tags: ios, swift, unicode

I want to format strings for RTL & LTR languages, so I guess I need to store unicode values `\u{200F}` for RTL & `\U{200E}` for LTR language, but I am confused how to store & use these values in localizedStringWithFormat. Normally I use this

```
var message1 = String.localizedStringWithFormat("\u{200F}%@ %d %@ %d", strOne,valueOne,strTwo,valueTwo)
```

Now while after storing unicode in a variable, how can I use that in string, and also if I store unicode value in string it give me \u{u2} for \u{200F}, how can I solve this ?

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't just an artefact of the debugger quoting special characters? What does `print(">\(message1)<")` show?

Comment: @MartinR it prints value stored in message